# Can my local ssh config show a message when accessing a particular host?

Tags: ssh

I am setting up a few SSH config entries for some new hosts. These hosts use a different credential than most of the other hosts in the environment. For various reasons keys are not an option here. Can I set up SSH config to show a message when I access a particular host?

Desired output:

```
me@localhost /home/work: ssh NewHost5
NewHost5 uses your Sorenson credentials, not your typical Corporate credentials!
Password:
```

Example SSH Config:

```
Host NewHost5
 User Frei.Heit
 HostName NewHost5.corporate.local
 HelpfulMessage NewHost5 uses your Sorenson credentials, not your typical Corporate
```

Is this possible?

I experimented with `LocalCommand` running `echo "my message"`. It shows the message but only after a successful login, I want the message to show before the password prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ProxyCommand`; its stderr is hidden but it can still write to `/dev/tty`.

```
ProxyCommand "cat ~/.ssh/Soreson_warn.txt > /dev/tty; nc %h %p"
```

The servers themselves can send a pre-login message using `Banner <file_path>` in sshd_config.

Comment: Does the proxy command actually start netcat in this case? I see that it appears to be a no-op usage of `nc` as the proxy command but will it leave a persistent copy running while ssh is still running?

Comment: Yes, the ProxyCommand has to keep running and pipe its stdin/stdout to the server.

Comment: This is extremely helpful for my issue (using `> /dev/tty`) however my use-case requires input as well as output. I posted my issue as a question, if anyone can help.... https://serverfault.com/questions/1117873/ssh-config-how-to-automatically-execute-an-interactive-script-locally-before-co